# useState changing even without setting the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am totally confused about this scenario , I am having a state variable called **listItems** setting the value for **listItems** using the api call inside **useEffect** now in the **handleChange** I am changing the particular object value inside the **listItems** but I didn't change the actual **listItems** value but if i console the **listItems** it's showing as updated value even without setList how come it happens?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import OrderSummary from './orderSummary'

export default function displayItems() {
  const [listItems, setList] = useState([]);
  const [order, setorder] = useState([]);
  var newarr = [];

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:3006/listItem', {

    })
      .then(function (resp) {
        let res = resp.data.sendList.response;
        let newRes = res.map((item) => {
          return item;
        })
        setList(newRes);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

  }, [])

  function handleChange(type,item) {
    var arrList=item;
    var newAr=[];
    if (type === 1) {
      arrList.quantity=arrList.quantity+1;
    }
    else if (type === 0 && item.quantity > 1) {
      arrList.quantity=arrList.quantity-1;
    }
    newAr.push(arrList);
    console.log("test",listItems) // value changes here dont know how
    //  setList(listItems);
  }

  function placeOrder(item) {
    newarr.push(...order, item);
    setorder(newarr)
  }

  return (
    <div className="col">
      <div className="row">
        <div classname="col-md-6">
        <p><b>Available Items</b> </p>
          {listItems && listItems.map((item) => {
            return (
              <div key={item._id}>
                <p>Name:{item.name}</p>
                <p>Description:{item.description}</p>
                <p>Cost:{'₹'}{' '}{item.cost}</p>
                <p>Quantity:{' '}
                  <i onClick={() => handleChange(1,item)} className="fa fa-plus-circle" />
                  <span className="text-center"><b>{item.quantity}</b></span><i onClick={() => handleChange(0,item)} className="fa fa-minus-circle" /></p>
                <div>
                  <button onClick={() => placeOrder(item)}>Add to order</button>
                </div>
              </div>)
          })}
        </div>
        {order && <OrderSummary orderItems={order} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

> [sandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-sunset-0b1zj)

Comment: inside `[]` put the item state `[listItems]` in useEffect() to check the changes of listItems

Comment: ya but without setting the value how the value changes ,kindly check the sandox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code `var arrList=item;` is an assignment by reference, it means that `arrList` and `item` are both references to the same object which explains the modification of the second when modifying the first, if you want to clone an object you can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or the [`Spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) or another solution:

```
var arrList = Object.assign({}, item);
// Or
var arrList = {...item};
```

**Working demo:**

[image: Edit wispy-dawn-xogze]

Comment: ok object assignment by reference this what i missed .. thanks

Comment: I am writing the same :-)